# Best Practices for Prolog predicates definition

Tags: prolog

I have defined the predicate duplicate_elements/2 whose definition is as follows:

duplicate_elements(L1, L2): L1 = [a,b], L2 = [a,a,b,b]

I would like to know, between the two alternatives 1 and 2, which one follows the best practices of Prolog:

```
duplicate_elements_1([],[]).
duplicate_elements_1([P | R],[P,P | T]) :- 
    duplicate_elements_1(R , T).
```

```
duplicate_elements_2([],[]).
duplicate_elements_2([P | R],[H1,H2 | T]) :- 
    H1 = P,
    H2 = P,
    duplicate_elements_2(R , T).
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which one follows the best practices of Prolog?

The first one.

Using =/2 is not common. I am not saying to avoid it but most production code tends to refactor them out.

For more info see: [Coding Guidelines for Prolog](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2899.pdf)

---

If you are using SWI-Prolog with [Single Side Unification](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ssu), then using =/2 is not only common but in some cases necessary.

See: [Example of refactoring code to SSU](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/example-of-refactoring-code-to-ssu/4713)

---

If you are using [listing/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=listing/1) to look at DCG code then you will see [=/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D)/2) used quite often. This is because the compiler is playing it safe and not refactoring the code to avoid introducing a bug.

Comment: Note this is a community wiki. I do not get the points for upvotes and most users can edit this. So if you want to add info edit this answer and please don't create another answer.